# Insert ASP.Net Controls into HTML template

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an html template, that describe the position of each control and templates are getting from database. I have added  certain custom tags like [txt],[chk] into html template. I want to replace this tags with asp.net controls like textbox,checkbox etc... at the time of page rendering. so i can write c# code on these controls.I want to implement these things on code behind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.net web forms, simply copy your HTML template into an ASPX page and replace your placeholders with the relevant controls you want to use.

If you are using ASP.Net MVC, then you can use Razor to do this. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-razor